# Доступ к команде бота(Discord js) в нескольких каналах

Tags: javascript, node.js

мне нужно сделать так, чтобы доступ к команде был сразу в 2 каналах, а в остальных его не было как можно это реализовать? `message.channel.id === ""` ведь берёт лишь 1 параметр.

Comment: `if (![100, 200].includes(message.channel.id)) return;`

Comment: Большое спасибо)